# help identify USB-like charging cable/connector (used in headphones)

Tags: cables

I need help in identifying the type/name for this cable and input pair.

I've been able to rule out existing cables that I already own and that I could determine online.

I used several sites that list USB cables for different types/revisions such as [this](https://www.cmd-ltd.com/advice-centre/usb-chargers-and-power-modules/usb-and-power-module-product-help/identifying-usb-connector/)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Most likely manufacturer specific. It would help narrow it down if you told what make/model those are.

Comment: That reminds me of the of the MHL (I think) compatible micro-USB connector on my old Samsung S3 phone.

Comment: @Justme i think you're right. the comments on Amazon seem to indicate its proprietary to Letscom.  here is the [product page](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07X3GVJFG/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&th=1).  I've contacted their support to see how/where I can obtain another

Comment: @xst or buy a product that does not force you to vendor lock-in.

Comment: @brhans interesting - I have only used MHL cables with regular micro-USB.

Comment: @Justme i agree on not buying these type of products.  I didn't intend on buying proprietary-requiring headphones, in fact a different version of this product uses normal micro-USB connectors and the product page on amazon is not explicit about these details